# concatenating existing strings within an array into new strings of a new array

Tags: string, concatenation, string-concatenation, arrays

I'm trying to get this program's groupPairs function to take the six Strings in an initial String array [One,Two,Three,Four,Five,Six] and create a new String array of half the size (3) with the original six Strings grouped sequentially in pairs [OneTwo,ThreeFour,FiveSix], and then return that resulting new String[] to the main method.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Application
{
    static String[] groupPairs(String[] array)
    {
        String[] newArray = new String[(array.length)/2];
        int count=0;
        for(String string:newArray)
        {
            newArray[count]=array[count].append(array[count+1]);
            count=count+2;
        }
        return newArray;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) //main method, don't worry about this
    {
        String[] list = new String[5];
        list[0]="One";
        list[1]="Two";
        list[2]="Three";
        list[3]="Four";
        list[4]="Five";
        list[5]="Six";
        String[] list2 = groupPairs(list);
    }
}
```

When trying to compile the program, I get this error:

```
Application.java:11: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method append(java.lang.String)
location: class java.lang.String
            newArray[count]=array[count].append(array[count+1]);
                                        ^
```

Any ideas on how to fix this line so that my new array will have concatenated pairs of the original String[] values would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform append operation on array. Try the following.

`String[] list = new String[6];`
`list[0] = "One";`
`list[1] = "Two";`
`list[2] = "Three";`
`list[3] = "Four";`
`list[4] = "Five";`
`list[5] = "Six";`
`String[] list2 = new String[list.length / 2];`
`for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < list.length; i++, j++)`
`{`
           `list2[j] = list[i] + list[++i];`
`}`